# Reordenar as variáveis do eixo X. Valores não alinhados aos valores do eixo Y

Tags: r

Olá, estou tentando fazer um gráfico de barras simples no ggplot com valores de detecções relacionados aos meses de um período de monitoramento. Mas no gráfico nem os valores nem a ordem correspondem aos dados da tabela me gerando um gráficos com valores trocados. Preciso que os valores fiquem na ordem da tabela com os valores corretos correspondentes.

```
detecs
Mês         Detecção
abril/19    78
maio/19     1093
junho/19    2017
julho/19    8355
agosto/19   9503
setembro/19 8667
outubro/19  5871
novembro/19 5429
dezembro/19 11540
janeiro/20  8412
fevereiro/20 2812
março/20    8068
abril/20    4352
maio/20     2591

ggplot(detecs,aes(x= Mês,y=Detecção))+  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A melhor maneira é transformar a coluna `Mês` em classe `"Date"`. Para isso, primeiro deve-se ter o dia. Um dia qualquer dá desde que exista, como por exemplo o 1º dia de cada mês.

```
x <- paste0("1/", detecs$Mês)
detecs$Data <- as.Date(x, format = "%d/%B/%y")
```

Agora, o gráfico vai ficar ordenado por data. Para ter a anotação do eixo dos `x` com `mês/ano` usa-se uma escala de datas.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(detecs,aes(x = Data,y = Detecção)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_x_date(
    name = "Mês", 
    date_breaks = "2 month",
    date_labels = "%b/%y"
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Dados

```
detecs <- read.table(text = "
Mês         Detecção
abril/19    78
maio/19     1093
junho/19    2017
julho/19    8355
agosto/19   9503
setembro/19 8667
outubro/19  5871
novembro/19 5429
dezembro/19 11540
janeiro/20  8412
fevereiro/20 2812
março/20    8068
abril/20    4352
maio/20     2591", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Entendi. Deu certo. Obrigada.